# How to pass data to a view controller within an container view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am just a novice in iOS programming.

I have recently encountered a tricky problem. The scenario is: I have an `UIViewController`(assume it's called A) now and it contains a container view, that container view contains a `UITableViewController`(let's call it B). I would like to pass simply a `NSMutableArray` from A to B when I press a `UIButton` in    `UIViewController`. However, since the design of embed segue enables the `UITableViewController's` `viewDidLoad` method to be executed immediately after `UIViewController` has loaded.

Does anyone have any idea of passing data in this scenario ? Just wondering...

Update:
[the storyboard of this two VC][1]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you cannot simply pass it in your prepareForSegue method like so:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    switch segue.identifier {

    case "tableViewController"?:
        if let tableViewVC = segue.destinationViewController as? TableViewVC {
            tableViewVC.myArray = passedArray
        } ...
```

Oh - obj-c would be something like this in pseudo code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(NSStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"tableViewController"]) {

    NSViewController *vc = [segue destinationController];
    if ([vc isKindOfClass:[tableViewVC class]]) {
        tableViewVC.myArray = passedArray;
```

Didn't see your tag :]

EDIT:
Here is a rough cut of what passing via notification could look like:
In your UIViewController's header declare:

```
#define nArrayReadyNotification @"ArrayReadyNotification"
```

In your UIViewController's .m file send the notification once the array should be sent:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: nArrayReadyNotification object:ARRAY];
```

In your tableView's viewDidLoad register for the notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(arrayReceived:) name: nArrayReadyNotification object:nil];
```

This would be your arrayReceived method in your table view:

```
- (void) arrayReceived:(NSNotification *)notificaiton {

NSArray *array = [notificaiton object];
if (array != nil) {

    ...
}
```

Finally in dealloc de-register your table view with:

```
- (void)dealloc {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

That should get it sent whenever you want - maybe off a timer. KVO would be my preference though.

Comment: thx for your reply. Well, my real question is that the viewDidLoad method is called too early. I have thought of alternatives such as using delegates to pass data though.

Comment: Ah - didn't quite get understand the last sentence of your main question. Table views are rarely loaded fully on viewDidLoad. There are several mechanisms you could use depending on your scenario. Key value observation is a pretty save bet. Another somewhat simpler way would be to fire of a notification. You could in fact pack an entire array into the object param of it.

Comment: yeah I meant that the TableViewVC's viewDidLoad is called(because of the container view). Notification would be a great way to try out.

Comment: Have you at all considered making your view controller the data source and/or delegate for your table view? That would of course be the obvious choice if your implementation allows it.

Comment: Since I created an TableViewController, the tableview delegate and data source delegate is set.

Comment: But you can change that. Try right dragging from your table view object to your view controller and re-assign it as your datasource / delegate instead. Then you need to designate your view controller as UITableViewDelegate in its header file and implement the protocol methods.

Answer (score 0):

ContainerView do 3 things

```
[A.view addSubview:B.view]
[A addChildViewController:B]
[B didMoveToParentViewController:A]
```

If you just want pass NSMutableArray from A to B, you can do this

```
UITableViewController *second = A.childViewControllers[0]
second.XXXXX = .....
```